# Converting an integer to be stored in a char* array

Tags: c, arrays, char, type-conversion

I have a `char**` array containing a kill command to be executed later in the code using `exec()`, with each entry containing a portion of the command. For example:

```
kill 1234
```

…will be represented as:

```
char **cmdList = {"kill","1234"};
```

Now, here's the problem: 1234 is initially of type `pid_t`, returned by `getpid()`. I cast this to an `int` and now I'm trying to figure out how I can convert it so that I can store it in the `char*` array. Here's what I have so far:

```
char *cmdList[10];  // There will never be more than 10 commands
cmdList[0] = "kill";
int pidHolder = (int)getpid();
char *pidChar = (char*)pidHolder; // How to convert int to char*?
cmdList[1] = pidChar;
printf("The job ID is %s \n", cmdList[1]); // Testing to see if it worked
```

As you can imagine, I get a segmentation fault here, but I can't seem to figure out another way to convert the int to the `char*` type.

Comment: `char *cmdList = {"kill","1234"}` is invalid. And don't cast unless you 1) really have to 2) understand and 3) accept **all** implications. In general avoid casts and use the correct types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf):

```
int aInt = (int)getpid();
char str[15];
sprintf(str, "%d", aInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[100];

sprintf(buffer, "kill %d", getpid());
```